# Mongodb-Rest queries with like

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am working with MongoDB 3.6.5 and Mongodb-rest (https://github.com/ashleydavis/mongodb-rest#installation),

I am trying to perform a "like" search and can do it via the mongo command line using: db.collection.find({"name" : /Smith/}); where I would search for all document that contain a "name" like "Smith".

How would I translate this to an HTTP REST call. I am having some difficulty passing the "/" in my query.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would your rest API care about mongodb query syntax?

Comment: Maybe I am missing some key point here but if I were to issue an http call: http://localhost:3000/collections/names?query={"name" : \/New Brunswick\/}, I get this an error complaining about json syntax

Comment: Please don't send the whole mongodb query from the client as this opens up the database to be exploited and also you can take it down with a $where operator

Comment: Considering it requires an ancient driver 1.4.7 https://github.com/ashleydavis/mongodb-rest/blob/master/package.json#L36 it is a miracle it works at all. Out of curiosity, which version of the database you are using? To answer the question - try a valid json: `{ "name": { "$regex": "Smith"} }`

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexBlex

Comment: Thank you @KevinSmith, I will heed the advice